# Elements won't lineup

Tags: html, css

I cannot lineup these three `<div>` (image is scaled down):
[image]

HTML:

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="position">
            <div id="content">
                <div id="logo">
                <div class="ref1">
                    <img src="ref/b_bi.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="ref2">
                    <img src="ref/b_mg.png" />
                </div>  
                <div class="ref3">
                    <img src="ref/b_sl.png" />
                </div>                       
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#logo
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 0;
    background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

}
.ref1
{
    width:250px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left:300px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.ref2
{
    width:250px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 550px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}   
.ref3
{
    width:250px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 800px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

}   
#container 
{ 
    display: table; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 95%; 
}
#position 
{ 
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    padding-top: 4%;
}
#content { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And like this?

```
#logo
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 0;
    background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

}
.ref1, .ref2, .ref3
{
    width:250px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#container 
{ 
    display: table; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 95%; 
}
#position 
{ 
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    padding-top: 4%;
}
#content { }
```

Comment: worked with a little change, I added padding-left:300px; to logo. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you wan't the DIVs to appear side by side? If so, you will need to add the style "float:left" to those DIVs (and get rid of the margins).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your margin-left's and possibly the width's of the classes.  If you remove the `margin-left`'s in `.ref2` and `.ref3` and add a `float:left`; to all 3 classes that should do what you want.  You may also need to remove or reduce your width's on all 3.

Here are the changes I would recommend starting with, you can play around with it once they are aligned how you want.

```
.ref1
{
    width:250px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left:300px;
    float:left;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.ref2
{
    width:250px;
    height: 400px;
    /*margin-left: 550px;*/
    float:left;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}   
.ref3
{
    width:250px;
    height: 400px;
    /*margin-left: 800px;*/
    float:left;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

}
```